# Show/hide every each dynamic children element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and I want to show child element which is the current whenever I selected form.

I've done so far but I couldn't achieve what I want to do

let me tell you with codes

After I click ADD button bottom of the form another form has been opening right of the exist form as you see image which has been uploaded below

[image]

[my demo link](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/QEAQoq)

and the div which is hide `.ekle` class I want to be appear `.ekle` div

and my js function

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 /** select seçim*/
    $('.havale_tipi').on('change', function (e) {
        var top_div = $(this).parents(".ekle").find(this);
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var indexSelected = this.index;
        var valueSelected = this.value;

        if(indexSelected=="iban_no"){
            $(".hesaba_form").fadeOut();
            $(".iban_no_form").fadeIn();
        }else if(indexSelected="hesaba_form"){
            $(".iban_no_form").fadeOut();
            $(".hesaba_form").fadeIn();
        }

    });

 /**select seçim bitiş*/

 /** form ekle **/
 $(".btn_ekle").on("click",function(e){
    var nesne = $(".ekle");
    var ekle = nesne.html();
    $(".add_after").append(ekle).show();
    e.preventDefault();
 })
 /** form ekle bitiş**/
});
```

Comment: Your codepen link is wrong.

Comment: @eisbehr thanks I fix it

Comment: If you can't reach the change function that dynamically created element you should create the function  like this: 
$(document).on('change','.havale_tipi',function(){ ... your code.....})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `.val()` to get the selected value
2. You have forgotten one `=` in your `else if` state
3. The value in the `else if` should be `hesaba` not `hesaba_form`, or remove the `else if` statement and use only `else`
4. To get your wish working, you should create a parent element inside your `elke` div, that wrapps the form. This helps to register the listener.
5. You should register a event listener with `on`, which even listens to elements coming up in the future.

HTML:

```
<div class="elke">
    <div class="group">
        <!-- your form here again -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn_ekle").on("click", function(e) {
        var ekle = $(".ekle").html();
        $(".add_after").append(ekle).show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.havale_tipi', function() {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            parent = $(this).closest(".group");

        if (value == "iban_no") {
            $(".hesaba_form", parent).fadeOut();
            $(".iban_no_form", parent).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".iban_no_form", parent).fadeOut();
            $(".hesaba_form", parent).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it great answer but if I click add button again new forms opening with children form as show what I have to do for it ?

Comment: and no if I selected form all hide div is appear only current child must be show

Comment: yes I understand but it works broken I don't understand why

Comment: So you should add an else statement like : 
else {
 $(".iban_no_form").fadeOut();
        $(".hesaba_form").fadeOut();
}
This will hide those unwanted divs.

Comment: so thans eisbehr :))

Comment: @eisbehr thanks for clear code I understand how to do thanks to you take care

Comment: what about removing current element I add remove element in html <p class="iade_sil">remove/<p> inside .group div and I wrote  $(".iade_sil").on("click",function(){
        $(this).parents(".add_after").find(".group").remove(); 
    }); but not work as expect

Comment: Please create a new question for this, @fortherest. This should not be done in the comments. ;) We will help you then ...

Comment: I did it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591176/remove-dynamic-current-element