# Remove dynamic current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form and Add button bottom of te form which is the right..and whenever click it's adding new a form with delete button and if I click it has to delete current form

my js code

```
$(".iade_sil").on("click",function(){
        $(this).parents(".add_after").find(".group").remove(); 
    });
```

and if you want you can see full demo and js files

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/VjdYWA)

Comment: When Ever you are going to add new form give some `dynamic Id` to particular form, and pass that `Form Id` on remove button, and remove from the `DOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the listener to watch all new elements too. And you want to use `closest`, not `parents`.

Even you dont need the `closest` too, you can select the `.group` directly, because your delete button is inside that element:

```
$(document).on("click", ".iade_sil", function() {
    $(this).closest(".group").remove(); 
});
```

Comment: but it remove all forms it has to delete just current :)

Comment: after 8 minute I'll vote your question so thanks eisbehr you'r so kind :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added DOM. You should also use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` and traverse to group element:

```
$(document).on("click",".iade_sil",function(){
    $(this).closest(".group").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use closest to that gorup class

```
$(document).on("click", ".iade_sil", function() {
    $(this).closest(".group").remove(); 
});
```